# Clicking a button in a webpage with javascript - error?

Tags: javascript

Noob Question; HTML is

```
    <button aria-label="Navigate to page 40" data-page- 
     number="40" type="button" data-ember-action="" data- 
      ember- 
      action-582="582" data-is-animating-click="true">
       40
     </button>
```

I thought the code would be

```
       document.querySelector('button.Navigate.to.page.40').click()
```

But apparently this isn't a valid selector... what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the selector `button[aria-label="Navigate to page 40"]`:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button[aria-label="Navigate to page 40"]');
console.log(button);
```

```html
<button aria-label="Navigate to page 40" data-page- number="40" type="button" data-ember-action="" data- ember- action-582="582" data-is-animating-click="true">
       40
     </button>
```

Your selector `button.Navigate.to.page.40` is valid, but it means: select a `<button>` which has classes of `Navigate`, `to`, `page`, and `40` (which of course isn't the case for this HTML).